# Polynomial ring with $p$-th root of unity

Tags: ring-theory, definition, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am trying to understand **Example 1.3** in the paper of Kedlaya *New methods for (phi, Gamma)-modules*, available in his [site](https://kskedlaya.org/papers/).

Firstly, Kedlaya defines two objects
$$ A:= \Bbb Z [x^{p^{-\infty}}] :=\bigcup_{n \ge 1} \Bbb Z[x^{p^{-n}}], \quad \hat{A}=\text{ $p$-adic completion of } A$$

--

**Q1:** How does one actually define $\Bbb Z[x^{1/k}]?$

My attempt: It should be the universal object mapping *into* a ring which has an element satisfyig
$$ x^k=x$$

A model of such an object should be the the polynomial ring with one variable
$$\Bbb Z[x]/(x^k-x) $$

---

**Q2:** Kedlaya claims $\hat{A}/(p) \cong \Bbb F_p [x^{p^{-\infty}}] $. How is this so  ?

My problem: I do not understand the description of $\hat{A}$ - or does this folllow formally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}[x^{1/k}]$ is simply (up to isomorphism) the ring of polynomials in the variable $x^{1/k}$. So $A$ is the ring of the finite sums $\sum_{k \geq 0}{a_kx^{k/p^n}}$, for all $n \geq 0$.

The product, for instance, is defined by $\sum_{k \geq 0}{a_kx^{k/p^n}} \cdot \sum_{l \geq 0}{b_lx^{l/p^m}}=\sum_{s \geq 0}{\left(\sum_{p^mk+p^nl=s}{a_kb_l}\right)x^{s/p^{n+m}}}$.

Thus, $\hat{A}$ is the ring of all the series $\sum_{\alpha}{a_{\alpha}x^{\alpha}}$, where $\alpha$ is a nonnegative rational with only a power of $p$ as its denominator, $a_{\alpha} \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, and $\{\alpha,\, |a_{\alpha}|_p > \epsilon\}$ finite for each $\epsilon > 0$.

When you quotient out by $(p)$, by the above description, you only get a finite sum $\sum_{\alpha}{a_{\alpha}x^{\alpha}}$, where $a_{\alpha} \in \mathbb{F}_p$ and $\alpha \in p^{-\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{N}$. These sums are exactly the elements of $\mathbb{F}_p[x^{p^{-\infty}}]$.

Comment: I have edited my question due to a typo. Does this still affect your answer?

Comment: I don’t think it changes anything.

Comment: Do you mean $\Bbb Z[x^{k^{-1}}]$  for the first sentence though? I'm also confused how you got that description of $\hat{A}$ - is there some general theory ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. For the second part, you “just” consider what it means to be a limit in the p-adic topology of elements of $A$.

Comment: As I understand it, the $p$-adic norm on $A$ is $|\sum_{k =0}^K a_k x^{k/p^n}|_A = \sup_k |a_k|_p$, then the completion is the set of series $\sum_j f_j$ with $f_j \in A$ and $\lim_{j\to \infty} |f_j|_A=0$, which gives what Mindlack said @BryanShih

Comment: @reuns: That’s exactly it, thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 2):

Each ${\mathbb Z}[x^{p^{-k}}]$ is an ordinary polynomial ring in one variable $x_k := x^{p^{-k}}$, and the union in question is formally the direct limit over the maps $\varphi_k: {\mathbb Z}[x_k]\to {\mathbb Z}[x_{k+1}]$ given by $x_{k}\mapsto x_{k+1}^p$. Alternatively, you might view it as the polynomial ring over the monoid ${\mathbb N}[\frac{1}{p}]\subset{\mathbb Q}$.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad on the generalization. I edited. 
So for $\Bbb Z[x^{p^{-k}}]$ one does not impose the condition that $x_k^{p^k} =x_k$?

Comment: No, you could construct it by adjoining $y$ with $y^{p^k}=x$ to ${\mathbb Z}[x]$, so it would rather be ${\mathbb Z}[x,y]/(y^{p^k}-x)$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yup, thanks that maakes sense.